# How can I identify if an item is a file or a directory using Net::SFTP?

Tags: ruby, perl, net-sftp

How to identify whether the item of a directory is a file or a directory using [`Net::SFTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP) or ruby code?

Answer (score 6):

The [`do_stat`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SFTP#%24sftp-%3Edo_stat%28%24path%29) method seems like it could get you that information. See also the documentation for [`Net::SFTP::Attributes`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SFTP::Attributes) and [`perldoc -f stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).

Answer (score 5):

To illustrate the use of [Manni's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803618/related-to-netsftp-directory/1803738#1803738):

```
use Fcntl(:mode);

my $permissions  = $sftp->do_stat($path)->perm();
my $is_directory = S_ISDIR($permissions);
```

Answer (score 1):

At least two ways to do it in SFTP and Ruby:

```
require 'net/sftp'
Net::SFTP.start('HOSTNAME', 'USER', :password => 'PASSWORD') do |sftp|

  file = File.expand_path(__FILE__)
  dir  = File.dirname(file)

  sftp.lstat!(file).directory?
  sftp.lstat!(dir).file?

  sftp.file.open(dir, "r") do |f|
    f.stat.file?
    f.stat.directory? # true
  end

end
```